# JavaScript form validation with a shake effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation

I have some JavaScript form validation I'm using before I send it across to my PHP. (I'm still learning). but my question for you today is how I would get my error message to shake without reloading the page. My below JS code seems to reload the page when I click submit. The error message style is set to `disply:none;` by default and only shows when needed.

I hope you understand what I am getting at. ha ha Thank you in advance.

Here's the js code.

```
function validateLoginForm() {
    var x = document.getElementById('email').value;
    if (x == null || x == "" || x == "Email") {
        document.getElementById('errorWrapper').style.display='block';
        document.getElementById('errorText').innerHTML='Please enter your Email address!';
        shakeIt();
        return false;
    }
}
```

and the jQuery.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function shakeIt(){
        $('#errorWrapper').effect("shake", { times:5, distance:8 }, 50);
    }
});
```

Comment: How are you calling `validateLoginForm()`?

Comment: in my form.
`<form action="index.php" name="loginForm" onsubmit="return validateLoginForm();" method="post" >`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do it on form.submit ie

```
$('#loginForm').submit(function(e){
var x= $('#email').val();
      if (x==null || x=="" || x=="Email")
      {
      $('#errorWrapper').show();
      $('#errorText').text('Please enter your Email address!');
      e.preventDefault();
      shakeIt();
      }
      return true;
});
```

Returning false will make the page not reload..

Comment: Do I need to add anything to `onsubmit=""` in my form? It seems to still be reloading the page.

Comment: You would probably have to remove the onsubmit tag. The above code would then handle submit being clicked.

Comment: I would also say, that your code is not checking that theres a valid email too so if any of your conditions werent met then the page would reload.

Comment: I do have validate email code. just didn't post it to try keep it simple.

Comment: I have updated my answer too. You should make sure the shakeIt() function is defined otherwise it will quit with an error before it hits e.preventDefault()

Comment: Hmmm Still not working for me. I got it to work perfectly on this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/beKAc/1/ just not on my website. Doesnt make sense.

Comment: If you look at my updated answer - it is the correct solution.. The return false was wrong - you need the (e) in the function and e.preventDefault() instead of return false.

Comment: no it does not work for me. I have triple checked. It kinda works in opera, but nothing else.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8712/discussion-between-steve-and-banjo)

Comment: No does not seem to be working on my site, although the JSFiddle works perfectly. I'm lost on this one.

Comment: got it! Was a silly random character that wasn't showing up until i put it in notepad. Thank you for all your help!